# Angular class does not implement inherited abstract member

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, ag-grid

While working on a program that I am facing an issue with, extending abstract class to shareable angular component

Here is my code:

**`AgGridDatasource` (aggrid.model.ts)**

```
export abstract class AgGridDatasource {

private _gridOptions: GridOptions = DEFAULT_GRID_OPTIONS;
private _gridApi: GridApi;
private _gridColumnApi: ColumnApi;

protected constructor(gridOptions: GridOptions) {
    this._gridOptions = Object.assign({}, this._gridOptions, gridOptions);
}

refreshColumns(): void {
    if (this._gridApi) {
        this._gridApi.setColumnDefs(this.createColumns());
    }
}

abstract createColumns(): AbstractColDef[];

onGridReady(event): void {
    this._gridApi = event.api;
    this._gridColumnApi = event.columnApi;
}

get gridOptions(): GridOptions {
    return this._gridOptions;
}

get gridApi(): GridApi {
    return this._gridApi;
}

get gridColumnApi(): ColumnApi {
    return this._gridColumnApi;
}
}
```

`AgGridComponent`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ag-grid',
  templateUrl: './ag-grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ag-grid.component.css']
})
export class AgGridComponent extends AgGridDatasource implements OnInit {
  @Input() columns: AbstractColDef[];
  @Input() datasource: any[];
  modules: Module[] = [ServerSideRowModelModule];
  rowCount?: number;

  protected constructor(gridOptions: GridOptions) {
    super(Object.assign({},{
      rowModelType: 'infinite',
      pagination: false,
      rowSelection: 'none',
      suppressCellSelection: true,
      cacheBlockSize: 100,
     },gridOptions));
  }

  createColumns() {
    console.log(`Getting input columns here`)
    console.log(this.columns)
    return this.columns;
  }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.gridOptions.datasource = this.dataSource;
    this.createColumns();
    this.refreshColumns();
  }

  dataSource: IDatasource = { 
    getRows(params: IGetRowsParams): void {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Getting updated input rows here`)
        console.log(this.datasource)
        params.successCallback(this.datasource, -1);
      }, 200);
    }
  }
}
```

Error Facing (updated):

[image]

[image]

[GITHUB REPO](https://github.com/imahmer/aggrid-helper)

**Scenario:**

I just started implementing ag-grid in my application.

I want to configure it programmatically, I want to put all agGrid configuration-related code into a separate abstract class in aggrid.model.ts

I want to use this `AgGridComponent` in all my application to configure agGrid so that I can manage the agGrid from a single place.

I am writing above code for that but looks like it is not working

Comment: You have `abstract createColumns(): AbstractColDef[];` in your abstract class. You need to implement that.

Comment: I appreciate your help with my question. Yes, I have now implemented the method but now the error was changed and I've updated my question with updated screenshots with the Github repo link as well. Kindly have a look and update your answer as well. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide the implementation of `createColumns` method in your component. Take `createColumns` method out of `ngOnInit` and make it a component instance method:

```
 protected createColumns() {
      return this.columns;
  }
```

and then you can call this method from `ngOnInit`.

One more point you should consider changing is removing the `protected` modifier from the constructor of  `AgGridComponent`. Since the constructor is protected, Angular will not be able to create an instance of this component. Change this to a `public` constructor.

Comment: I appreciate your help with my question. Yes, I have now implemented the method but now the error was changed and I've updated my question with updated screenshots with the Github repo link as well. Kindly have a look and update your answer as well. Thanks

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, I've checked it by removing the protected modifier from my constructor but still, it gives me a lot of errors and not building my code. can you please check my repo and what actually I'm doing wrong?

Comment: my scenario is not yet full-filled but as you pick what I'm doing wrong in my code I accepted your answer.

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan I think, what you are trying to achieve is already implemented here, take a look: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ag-grid-angular

Comment: please also have a look on my another thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69338449/ag-grid-request-start-row-and-end-row-property-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score 1):

I have forked your repo, run it, and ...:

1. First I've deleted the `protected` access modifier from `AgGridComponent`'s constructor that was causing: `Type 'typeof AgGridComponent' is not assignable to type 'Type<any>'. Cannot assign a 'protected' constructor type to a 'public' constructor type.`, basically that means that TypeScript has no way of instantiate `AgGridComponent` if its constructor is protected only usable by itself and its children, so, run it again ...
2. And then, I realized that you are trying to inject the interface `GridOptions` as an object dependency into `AgGridComponent`, and there is the problem I think ...

Because what the Angular injector will be doing is trying to instantiate all the parameters within a component's constructor with the `new` key word, therefore, because `GridOptions` is an interface and can't be instantiated, well, then Angular complaints:

`No suitable injection token for parameter 'gridOptions' of class 'AgGridComponent'. Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.`

So, maybe you should create another class maybe decorated with `@Injectable()`, that implements `GridOptions` interface and then you would be good to go injecting it into `AgGridComponent`'s contructor.